# Do we need $\Lambda$ be bounded in Riesz Representation Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

Do we need $\Lambda$ be bounded in Riesz Representation Theorem? In papa Rudin theorem 2.14, it doesn't mention $\Lambda$ is bounded. But from another online resource, it said any **bounded** linear functional T on the space of compactly supported continuous functions on X is the same as integration against a measure $\mu$.

So that is my question. Is bounded required in Riesz Representation Theorem?

Comment: The wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%E2%80%93Markov%E2%80%93Kakutani_representation_theorem should answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need $\Lambda$ to be bounded. If $\Lambda$ is unbounded, the corresponding regular measure $\mu$ can have value $+\infty$. This is why you only consider compactly supported functions, so that the integrals are guaranteed to be finite.

More specifically, let $f \in C_c(X)$. The integral $ \int_X f d\mu $ better be finite if we want any hope for the identity $ \Lambda(f) = \int_X f d\mu $ to make sense. Fortunately, it is indeed finite, because $\mu$ is finite on any compact set.

However, if $\Lambda$ is in fact bounded, then we can assert more. In this case, the corresponding measure $\mu$ is also finite, and the identity $ \Lambda(f) = \int_X f d\mu $ is true for all continuous functions vanishing at infinity $f \in C_0(X)$.

Actually, we have the following theorem:

> **Riesz–Markov–Kakutani representation theorem**
>
> Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space. For each regular complex
> Borel measure $\mu$ on $X$, define $ \Lambda_\mu: C_0(X) \to \mathbb{C} $
> by
>
> $$ \Lambda_\mu(f) = \int_X f d\mu \quad \text{for} \quad f \in C_0(X) $$
>
> Then the map $ \mu \mapsto \Lambda_\mu $ is an isometric isomorphism
> between the space of regular complex Borel measures on $X$ and the
> dual space of $C_0(X)$.

The space of regular complex Borel measures on $X$ is a Banach space with the total variation $|\mu|(X)$ as the norm. The above theorem asserts that $ |\mu|(X) = ||\Lambda_\mu|| $. Note that a complex measure by definition must have finite total variation.